# Why do I get this error? invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c, boolean-operations

I want to check if 2 struct pointers point to the same values, but I get this error:

./07ex.c:158:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('RGB' (aka 'struct RGB_') and 'RGB')
return *x == *y;
Here is the struct and the function:

```
typedef struct RGB_ {
    float r; 
    float g; 
    float b; 
} RGB;

bool point_to_equal_values_struct(RGB *x, RGB *y) {
    return *x == *y;
}
```

I got through this by doing it as such:

```
bool point_to_equal_values_struct(RGB *x, RGB *y) {
    if ((*x).r == (*y).r && (*x).g == (*y).g && (*x).b == (*y).b)
    {
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}
```

But still, I am curious as to why the compiler gives out this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this were C++, I'd say "you didn't define any `operator==` on your `RGB` class". In C you can not even overload operators, so you'll have to write a function like `is_rgb_equal` that compares two `RGB` structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator isn't defined to work on structs, so two structs can't be compared directly.

You need to compare the corresponding fields as you did.  On a side node, you probably want to use the `->` operator to access members of a struct referenced by a pointer as it's easier to read:

```
if (x->r == y->r && x->g == y->g && x->b == y->b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @dbush answer, you can also if the structs are packed:

```
if(!memcmp(x,y, sizeof(*x)))
{
   /* do something */
}
```

Members access of packed structures can be quite expensive and `memcpy` can be more efficient.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work due to padding.

Comment: *Not generally!!!* In this *specific* case, yes, as all members have the same size and no padding bytes will be added (usually, at least, but that's again not guaranteed!); if sizes differ, exactly this might happen, though, and the content of these padding bytes is indeterminate, but they are included in the comparison!

Comment: @dbush phone call distracted me. I meant packed structs where individual members access can be expensive.